# pthread_cond_timedwait ret 22 but errno is success

Tags: linux, pthreads

I am calling `pthread_cond_timedwait` in which I am setting below  timeout value

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &timeout);
//timeout.tv_sec+= 1;
timeout.tv_nsec+= 100000000;
ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&Cond, &Mtx, &timeout);
```

However, after some time I am getting ret value 22 but errno is success.

If I enable `timeout.tv_sec` and comment out `timeout.tv_nsec` then I am not seeing any issue and I am always getting ret value zero, however vice-versa is not working.

Can anyone help me understand why `pthread_cond_timedwait` returns 22 however `errno` is zero?

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone help me understand why pthread_cond_timedwait returns 22 however errno is zero?

Pthreads functions may or may not set `errno` value; their return values represent the error values. You can assign `ret` to `errno` and call `perror()` or `strerror()`.

> However, after some time I am getting ret value 22 but errno is success.

You say the return value of `pthread_cond_timedwait()` value is 22 (which is usually `EINVAL`), it indicates the problem lies with `timeout.tv_nsec` value you pass.

[POSIX manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) says:

> EINVAL
>   The abstime argument specified a nanosecond value less than zero or greater than or equal to 1000 million.

Since you do:

```
timeout.tv_nsec+= 100000000;
```

it's likely that `timedout.tv_nsec` already contains some value and adding 100 million to that results in `EINVAL`. If the above code is in a function and that's called repeatedly, then at the 10th call, `timeout.tv_nsec` will get to 1000 million. I suggest you ensure `timeout.tv_nsec` is less than 1000 million and try again.

For example, do:

```
timeout.tv_nsec = 100000000;
```

instead of:

```
timeout.tv_nsec += 100000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you add a value to the nano seconds without checking for an overflow. The correct code would be:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &timeout);
timeout.tv_nsec += 100'000'000;
if(timeout.tv_nsec >= 1'000'000'000)
{
    timeout.tv_sec += 1;
    timeout.tv_nsec -= 1'000'000'000;
}
ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&Cond, &Mtx, &timeout);
```

As mentioned by P.P, the returned value from `pthread_cond_timedwait()` is what is usually expected in the `errno` variable. I would suggest that you change the name of your variable to something that better represents what is returned (maybe `e` or `err`).

From the [docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html):

> ### ERRORS
>
> `pthread_cond_init`, `pthread_cond_signal`, `pthread_cond_broadcast`, and `pthread_cond_wait` never return an error code.
>
> The `pthread_cond_timedwait` function returns the following error codes on error:
>
> **ETIMEDOUT**
>     the condition variable was not signaled until the timeout specified by `abstime`
>
> **EINTR**
>     `pthread_cond_timedwait` was interrupted by a signal
>
> **EPERM**
>     The mutex type is `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` or the mutex is a robust mutex, and the current thread does not own the mutex.
>
> The `pthread_cond_destroy` function returns the following error code on error:
>
> **EBUSY**
>     some threads are currently waiting on `cond`.

Another error you often get is the `EPERM`. In most cases, this is because your mutex or condition were not correctly initialized or the current thread did not lock the mutex before the call.

*Note: the ticks in the numbers work since C++11, remove them if your compiler is not happy about them.*